# Create QR codes per single product purchased

Tags: magento2, code

Hello to the community!

I have the necessity to create QR codes per every single product that's purchased.
I know that there's a way to link a SKU to a QR code, but what I need to do is a little more complicated.

Let's say that user X buys 3 units of SKU A, 2 units of SKU B and 1 unit of SKU C.

What I'll need is a total of 6 QR codes:
 - 3 QR codes for SKU A (because the user X bought 3 units of the same product)
 - 2 QR codes for SKU B (because the user X bought 2 units of the same product)
 - 1 QR code for SKU C (because the user X bought a single unit of this product).

This, of course, means that I would generate the QR codes **after** the payment has been finalised.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

LDR

Comment: The QR Code is for a Download-Link for each product?

Comment: No, it's not.
The QR code links to a physical item that can be purchased, but also resold. That's why I need a different QR code for each item that has been purchased. 
The "resell" value depends on the product itself, who bought the product and how much the product was bought for.

Comment: Why you need QR codes in this case? Please explain the workflow a little bit.

Comment: We are working with a physical store that would also like t sell through an e-commerce. The products are never shipped, but they can be purchased online and collected at the store. Whenever an item is sold, it has a resell value. This resell value, that changes over time (let's say every hour), has to be linked to a QR code.
This serves two purposes:
- The customer can scan the QR code anytime to know the resell value.
- When the customer decides to sell it back to the store, he brings the item along with the QR code so that it can be scanned by the owner to know the resell value.

Comment: I know I can use this library:
http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/
but it requires a url to generate the png with the QR code. Question is: how can I create a univocal URL that links to only one of the item purchased? Keep in mind, three items purchased of the same product requires three separate URLs.